# Code2000 says it has 晣 but it will not print it

Tags: fonts, luatex, characters, japanese, chinese

In fact it does not print other more simple Chinese characters either. I checked that it supports 晣 by looking [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6663/fontsupport.htm). So i downloaded it from [here](https://fonts2u.com/code2000.font). I put the `TTF` in the same directory as the `tex` which is

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CODE2000.TTF}

\begin{document}
晣i
\end{document}
```

You will see the `i` printed but not 晣. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try downloading the file at http://www-sul.stanford.edu/depts/sysdept/info/CODE2000.TTF (I don’t much trust the site you used, and the file sizes are very different).

Comment: It's interesting how `CODE2000` got it wrong. You can put 日 below instead of on the left but you can't change it to 目. Maybe just divert your comment to an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original website for Code 2002 no longer exists.

[fonts2u.com](https://fonts2u.com/), which has never struck me as a reliable site, provides an old version, version 1.13, of three megabytes, and FontForge reports many errors when opening it.

[Stanford University](http://web.stanford.edu/dept/SUL/library/prod/depts/sysdept/info/code2000.html) hosts a newer version, version 1.16, of 7.5 megabytes, and your minimal example runs perfectly with this version.

However, you can do still better: the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20110108105420/http://code2000.net/) has what appears to have been the last version released, version 1.171, of 8 megabytes:

[image]